# setInterval for individual functions

Tags: javascript, timer, setinterval

Trying to test level ups in a game. The idea is after a certain period of time a function gets called, however I don't want it to be called every (n) seconds I just want it called once:

```
setInterval(level1, 10000);

function level1() {
alert ("LEVEL 1");

}

setInterval(level2, 50000);

function level2() {
alert ("LEVEL 2");

}
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, wouldn't using "setTimeout" instead of "setInterval" solve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use setTimeout for one time;

```
setTimeout(level1, 10000);
```